# Tizen Studio Run Error on real device - Error 61

Tags: debugging, sdk, ide, config, tizen

I try to launch a webapp in tizen studio on my Gear S but always get
a fatal error (see picture). I correctly added the certification - newest
sdk. With the emulutar it is no problem, only on the real device. I cant choose by clicking right on the device add permissions - the permission slot is just empty.

Some ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed [here](https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Wearable), Gear S has version 2.2.1.4 of Tizen platform. Please check if required version of your application is higher than 2.3. If so, modify config.xml and set 2.2.1.4 as your required version (You'll find it in `<tizen>` tag).

If your device show up in connection explorer and If you correctly create certificates you will get `Succeeded to uploaded a certificate` message when you click on "Permit to install applications" option.

Hope you'll be able to install applications now.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried it and got new trouble with certification...In the current Tizen IDE the certification handling is quite different i think (only a manager ui available). Do you know how i can upload the device-profile.xml to target ?

Comment: Which kind of trouble ? You don't have to upload it to target separately. Create your author and distributor certificate from `Tools>Certificate Manager`. The `device-profile.xml` will be created automatically using your information from here.

Comment: finally it works perfectly - thx ! I had to upload a destrib certif to the device and change the sdk version as you mentioned. Thanks a lot dude !